# Jquery trying to add a text input to each column header in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get it to append a text input to display below the header span but it seems to be doing some wonky stuff -

It appears to not be doing it. I have written this once in C# and I am currently having to basically port it over to ClietnSide due to some bugs that can only be fixed using clientside.

https://jsfiddle.net/fgtzjbLu/

```
 var $input = $("<input/>", {
            type: "text",
                       
            placeholder: "Column Filter"
        }); 
 $tr.append("<th>" + "<span>" + colHeader[i] + '</span>' + '<br />').append($input.clone()).append("</th>");
```

Comment: I got it to add the textboxes however it is doing something weird. 
`$tr.append("<th>").append(colHeader[i]).append($input.clone()).append("</th>");`

https://jsfiddle.net/gsoqxt7e/
I updated the fiddle and you can see it seems like the header columns and data are not aligned now

Comment: `append` cannot append partial elements.

Comment: Where is it partial

Comment: As @connexo mentioned your append is partial because you're splitting an element (TH) within 2 appends.  Contactenate instead. E.g.: ```JS
 $tr.append("<th>" + "<span>" + colHeader[i] + '</span>' + '<br />'+$input.clone()+"</th>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out -

After the table is completed I have run the following code to insert the textbox into each column header.

```
 var tid = 10;
    var $input = $( "<input/>", {
        type: "text",
        id: id+tid + "TXTSEARCH",
        placeholder: "Filter",
        'class': 'SearchTextBox',
    });  
   
    $($table.find('th')).each(function () {
  
        $input.clone().prop('id', id + tid + "TXTSEARCH",'placeholder',"Column Search").appendTo($(this));
        tid++;
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8fjo2gv/